# Paste text stored on Clipboard to a variable using pbpaste

Tags: terminal, copy-paste

I have some text stored on my clipboard. I want to store this text onto a shell script "variable".

So something like:

```
ls -altr > pbcopy
tmp="something"
pbpaste > $tmp    # this doesn't get the ls command output :(
echo $tmp         # should not print something
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
ls | pbcopy
tmp=$(pbpaste)
```

And don't forget to remove the files called `pbcopy` and `something` you created with your first and second line.

Comment: lol @patrix...thanks for that. extra points for humor.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me...

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -altr | pbcopy
tmp=`pbpaste`
echo $tmp
```

You needed a pipe rather than redirect on the `pbcopy` line and you can use `=` to assign `tmp` to the result of `pbpaste` - remembering the backticks around `pbpaste`, of course, otherwise it will just echo the word "pbpaste"!

Comment: Thanks @binarybob, this solution works too. yup backticks is important, also not to be mistaken for single quotes '